# I would like to set up Simplechan?

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, virtualbox

I want to make a bulletin board similar to `4chan` on `linux (ubuntu)` on virtualbox.
I was able to create a database, but I can not import a sql file from here to create a table.

```
https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan
```

I'd like to set up a bulletin board on this site, but now I have been able to create databases.

```
\ i create_table_query.sql

\ i functions.sql

\ i functions_moderator.sql
```

If I enter it like this, it seems I can do it, but it says `"There is no command to create"`. Someone please tell me! !

Comment: Are you typing those in postgresql shell?

Comment: Yes. I entered these commands after specifying the user and entering the database.

Comment: Did you put space between \ and i? there is no space in the documentation. And the files are under `sql` directory. So you'll have to `cd sql` before you enter the db.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: "You need to cd sql before entering db.
What kind of command should I enter?
If you enter "cd sql" from nothing to enter,
"-bash: cd: sql: No such file or directory" will be displayed.